# Extracting Object of Interest OpenCV using IR images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction

I have an image of an object taken in the night(grayscale) using IR camera and its daytime image in RGB captured in the same position and angle. I want to use the night time image since it contains depth information to extract the outline of the object.

This is the what I came up with:

1. Using the IR image, pixels that are bright are features of the objects that are close to the camera and vice versa.
2. For every bright pixel in IR image pick its counterpart in the color image and everything else can be assumed to be part of background.

How can I do these steps in OpenCV?

I don't have my own images yet. Here is a sample image which is close to what I will be getting.

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Oo1bAB8u5Ec/UEp69IgtL9I/AAAAAAAAGiA/M6Sk3d2Fw0g/s1600/owlcrow.jpg

I would like to trace the outline of the tree and the branch here.

Comment: Posting some sample image might be helpful for the viewers.

Comment: I have added an image as requested.

Comment: OpenCV has contours.... Just feed it a binary image which you can achieve by getting the threshold values of anything not black